# Basic installation of Umbraco seems to work, but cannot log in

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

Just used the web installer package from the Umbraco website. All seemed to go fine. The website prompts me for username and password and when I log in, chrome dev tools shows:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (You must login to view this resource.)

DependencyHandler.axd?s=L3VtYnJhY28vdW1icmFjby9saWIvanF1ZXJ5L2pxdWVyeS5taW4uanM7L3VtYnJhY28vdW1icmF…:12 No url found for api name legacyTreeJs(anonymous function) @ DependencyHandler.axd?s=L3VtYnJhY28vdW1icmFjby9saWIvanF1ZXJ5L2pxdWVyeS5taW4uanM7L3VtYnJhY28vdW1icmF…:12

DependencyHandler.axd?s=L3VtYnJhY28vdW1icmFjby9saWIvanF1ZXJ5L2pxdWVyeS5taW4uanM7L3VtYnJhY28vdW1icmF…:16 GET http://localhost:8099/umbraco/umbraco/backoffice/UmbracoApi/Authentication/GetRemainingTimeoutSeconds 401 (Unauthorized)
```

...and the message `"Session timed out. Log in below"` appears on the login page.

Comment: A few things to check: Is your db created? Does the website have write access to app_data? Is your website in full trust mode?

Comment: I deleted it all and manually created an IIS site. This time it worked. Something in the automated script obviously disagrees with my server!